# Why is Gnuplot's -e flag not working inside bash script in this case?

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I am running a bash script that, among other things, invokes Gnuplot.

Suppose I have a file named `foo.dat`, containing some data points, like:

```
1.0 1.0
2.0 2.0
3.0 3.0
```

Now, if I run the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="foo.dat"
echo gnuplot -e "\"plot '"$file"' using 1:2;pause -1\""
gnuplot -e "\"plot '"$file"' using 1:2;pause -1\""
```

My shell outputs the following:

```
gnuplot -e "plot 'foo.dat' using 1:2;pause -1"

"plot 'foo.dat' using 1:2;pause -1"
^
line 0: invalid command
```

If I run `gnuplot -e "plot 'foo.dat' using 1:2;pause -1"` directly on the terminal emulator's command line, however, the output is the expected.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Too many quotes: You're tell gnuplot to run the `"plot` command, when you mean `plot`.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct indeed. It is wrong to put those "extra" quotes, since the input after ```-e``` is already known to be a string. Only directly in CLI are those "extra" double quotes needed, unlike inside the script.

Comment: You can also do it readably with a *"heredoc"* like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61015917/2836621

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was "too many quotes", as pointed out by @larsks in the comment section. If my bash script consists of

```
#!/bin/bash
file="foo.dat"
gnuplot -e "plot '"$file"' using 1:2;pause -1"
```

the command runs just fine. Probably because `plot...` is already known by bash to be a string, unlike a command directly typed in the command-line interface, where I would have to delimit the string coming after the flag `-e`.